# Get location of file accessed through environment variable

Tags: c++, windows, environment-variables

How do I get the location of a file accessed through the environment variable.
I'd like it to be like the `where` command in the windows command prompt.
I'm currently using `_popen("where python","r");` but it opens a dos window briefly.
I've looked into using `_popen` without the dos window and `CreateProcess` seems overkill for something this simple.

Comment: Do you really need the location? The path that `where` returns is the one that will be used anyway (i.e. just `_popen("python")`).

Comment: I'm not trying to run python, I'm trying to find where it's located and this seemed like the way to go. I did find the location of python in PATH but it gets muddled because I also have python/scripts in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SearchPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365527.aspx) fits the bill as long as you're willing to put an extension on the file. As in:

```
WCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
DWORD result = SearchPath(NULL, L"python.exe", NULL, MAX_PATH, buffer, NULL);
if (result > 0)
{
    std::wcout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

If putting an extension on the filename is too much, you could iterate over all of the values in the `PATHEXT` environment variable and try each one.

Comment: Oh, that's much better than my suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You can use LoadLibrary() on the executable, then ask for its location using GetModuleFileName().  This does have side-effects however, as the EXE is actually loaded as a module.

Other than that, you can look for the file yourself using the [search order of CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).

Sorry I don't think either of these options are especially good, but I can't find anything else.